# Error in handling POST method for Flutter application

Tags: mysql, node.js, flutter

I am currently doing an application where for the Profile page, I constructed a simple form to update the user's Name and Gender. When I click Save, flutter does not display any error but the server-side returns an error.

The backend runs on Node.js and MYSQL as the database

This is my HTTP POST method for Flutter

```
Future<bool> updateProfile(String name, String gender) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    final Map<String, dynamic> profileData = {

      'name': name,
      'gender': gender
    };
    try {
      print( json.encode(profileData));
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
          'http://10.0.2.2:3030/profile/updateprofile',
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json",},
          body: profileData);

      if (response.statusCode != 200 && response.statusCode != 201) {
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        return false;
      }
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseData);
      final Profile newProfile = Profile(
          profileId: responseData['profileId'], 
          name: name, 
          gender: gender);
      _profile.add(newProfile);
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This is the code for the Update Profile form

```
void _submitForm(Function updateProfile) {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    updateProfile(
      _titleTextController.text,
      _formData['gender'],
    ).then((_) => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/myprofile'));
  }
```

This is the error returned at the server-side (NodeJS)

```
 body: {},
  route:
   Route {
     path: '/updateprofile',
     stack: [ [Layer] ],
     methods: { post: true } } }
{ SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: profile.name cannot be null
    at Promise.all.then (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:74:15)
    at tryCatcher (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
    at PromiseArray._resolve (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:126:19)
    at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:144:14)
    at Promise._settlePromise (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (D:\HTDOCS\MDFOLIO\PinkBook\back-end\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
  name: 'SequelizeValidationError',
```

Comment: "Violation: profile.name cannot be null" Have you been able to create a check in your flutter code that prevents a null name from being sent in the first place?

Comment: I just altered my controller and set allowNull value to true. So the data is able to be passed with a status code 200 -  this indicates the profile is updated but is returning an empty body.

Comment: Have you used a listener for text changes? Using the debugger pause the app on the '_titleTextController.text' and check that the controller has actually updated and still not blank.

Comment: Yesterday I found out an alternative solution. I replaced the **http** package with **dio** and it worked! The post method returned a body of String values just as expected!